# Using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack with CollapsiblePanelExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

When setting the Page directive for MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack to true on pages with CollapsiblePanelExtenders, the page does not properly maintain the scrolling position once a postback is made.

I've noticed that once the postback is made, the browser attempts to scroll to the original position *before* the collapsible panels are expanded again (as they are loaded in a collapsed state, and then expanded on the client side), and so the scrolling position either does not move at all or it makes it only part way.

One potential solution I can think of is to wrap the affected panels in an UpdatePanel to avoid the hard postback altogether, but this is not particularly ideal since this issue affects multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

You could capture the state of the CollapsiblePanelExtender into a HiddenField, then deal with the state of the CollapsiblePanelExtender serverside during the postback.

There are some examples [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1182064.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but actually the panel is maintaining the collapsed/expanded state perfectly fine. It's just that after the postback, the scroll position is being adjusted _before_ the panels are expanded again (as they are rendered collapsed before being automatically expanded). This all happens in a split second so I suppose it just depends on the sequence of events. If there was a way to have the state of the panel be pre-set before the render, it would likely resolve the problem.

Comment: That's what I'm saying you should do: capture the state of the panel serverside and set how it renders serverside so that when it is sent to the browser expanded, the MaintainScrollPosition works.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Yes, that makes sense. I will give it a shot and respond back here with the result. Thanks.

Comment: I realized that there are far too many ways to trigger a postback on the page, so just to test I added a OnPreRender event to the panel and even changed the default Collapsed state of the extender to "false". Even when the panel is expanded, the scroll position is not maintained. To me, this means that I should just opt for the UpdatePanel to fix the problem unless you think I wasn't thorough enough.